# SQL order stop at ID

Tags: mysql

I have the MySQL table `ID`, `username`, `points`.

I am trying to order the table by points (several users can have the same amount of points), however: I am trying to only have the entries before a certain ID. So, if the query first makes an ordered table, I would like to have all its entries, sorted, but stop at ID = '40', because I'm only interested at the players who are ordered higher (not necessarily better, they can have the same amount of points) than the player #40.

If it is, then how is it possible?

EDIT: No, I do NOT want to limit the query results to 40 rows, for I do not know how many players are better than player #40. I only want the query to stop at the entry with ID=40, NOT with row_number=40.

EDIT 2: Problem is: the players with more points than player #40 can still have higher IDs, which is why it's not possible to just say `WHERE ID <= 40`.

EDIT 3:

[image]

Seeing this picture, I simply want the results from player `him` until player `jackpot`, ALTHOUGH player `friend` has the same amount of points as `jackpot` has. Is that possible somehow? The names are arbitrary, by the way, I just didn't think of any better usernames.

Comment: based on your edits - what is the significance of stopping at ID = 40 then? Perhaps I am missing some detail

Comment: It is significant, because if I stopped based on the points, and then counted the results (which will be later, I know, I only need to use `count(*)`, but never mind), anyway, if I counted the results, it would make the positions of the players with the same amount of points the same. However, based on MySQL's sorting, I want their positions to be different despite their same amount of points.

Comment: What you are describing is not only NOT possible - it doesn't even make sense. You state that "you" is included based on the image with 30 points and ID of 70 but "friend" with 30 points and ID of 50 is not. Note: I did not downvote you (yet) because I am holding onto the idea you may be leaving out some key information but this is an awful question so far with very little thought put into it.

Comment: ok, never mind, sorry for bothering you. I can no longer delete this question, though.

Comment: sorry to be rude initially. SO users want to know the question is fully thought out and makes sense before it it asked. I think the answers below may get what you are looking for but ultimately you don't have a true 'sort' rule based on your requirements. Once that is developed, a query could easily be put together.

Comment: Really, never mind ;) It really was important to sort by the points but stop at different entries, buuut, seeing that it's impossible to do using MySQL, I've figured out a way to do it outside. No bid deal, and no offense, really ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you question correct, you are looking for a list of players who have more points than the point value of player at id 40.

If so:

> SELECT * FROM table WHERE points > (SELECT b.points FROM table b WHERE
>   b.ID = '40') ORDER BY points DESC

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be as simple as this ? :

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `id` <= '40' ORDER BY `id`,`username`,`points`
```

Of course you can adapt the query to your table by changing the `table_name` to the actual one, and if you don't want to select all columns replace the `*` by the list of fields you want...

In case i didn't get it either, let me know what i missed and i'll edit my answer